# Are there solid reasons not to use jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I see some disagreement against its use from time to time, but what distinct, objective disadvantages are there?  As far as I can see it tends to take the most efficient routes to implementations and the overhead is minimal.  So what's the problem?  Of course it can't do everything, but for what it can do why not use it?

Comment: About the only reason I can think of is that it's yet another file to download, and even compressed and minified it is not negligible.  In some cases it can interfere with other javascript, but there are typically ways around that problem.

Comment: Dont worry, its just a bunch of javascript elitists who say not to use it......they learnt web design in 2003 and learnt direct DOM manipulation with pure javascript.....so they feel special....theyre too stuck in their ways to give up old ways....or they just wanna look like they write more code to look smarter....who knows.  They probably still use 52 lines to do an ajax call.

Comment: A closely related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9591974/should-i-use-jquery-or-vanilla-javascript-for-my-web-app

Comment: I think the real reason some people get pissed about Jquery is because so many people only know Jquery without knowing real javascript, and that pisses off the real programmers.....who think if you're gonna use a framework you must understand the components first.  That could be argued either way.....its like, you wanna drive a porsche, well heres a manual on how to build an engine, now read it before I give you the porsche....human nature says you just wanna drive the porsche, you dont give a f*** how it works... lol  arg, such a stupid analogy

Comment: imgur wrote something about it recently: http://imgur.com/blog/2013/05/21/tech-tuesday-jquery-dom-performance/

Comment: @KyleK I used pure javascript in 2003 and did ajax calls and was very happy with that :). It was just few lines not 52.

Comment: @Alex, well I was obviously just exaggerating ;) ...but yeah doing XHR requests with pure javascript was at the least 13-20 lines.  Jquery can do it in one, in certain situations....

Comment: @KyleK I totally understand that, but my stance is to learn as little as possible about things I don't need so I can put that energy into learning other things.  It's not that I'm not learning, I'm just learning efficiently.

Comment: @KyleK When I found JQuery it looked more complex for me at first than pure javascript.

Comment: @Alex....its so not :)  But I guess it depends on what you learn first....I learnt Jquery before javascript per-se....I now know both....and can use both....but Javascript seemes so verbose, after I had already used Jquery

Answer (score 1):

Some of the element selectors it offers do not give good performance e.g. reg-ex based element selector or css class based element selector. These selectors crawl entire DOM to fetch all matching elements. Similarly other DOM manipulation capabilities like moving back and forth in DOM using "prev" and "next" methods would be slow. All the overheads which are there should be considered keeping in mind the browsers/OS combination.